# How to add an app icon to the IOS native share?

Tags: ios, icons

I added the ability to share information from my app, but the native share menu presents this white default icon next to the "text to share" instead of my app icon.

This is the code I used to show the share window -

```
NSString* nsTitle = UTF8_TO_PSTR(title);
NSArray* activities = @[nsTitle];
UIActivityViewController* sharingController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activities applicationActivities:nil];

[navigationController presentViewController:sharingController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How can I add my app icon to the share window?
I already have some icons in the AppIcon.appiconset folder, but it doesn't use them.

[image: native share missing app icon]